# Is there a less verbose way of scanning substrings, depending on whether starting from the start or end of a string?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a function that scans substrings of a given string, starting from either the front or back of said string. Is there a less verbose way of writing this (i.e., without using separate loops depending on whether `reverse` is true or false)? I apologize for the poorly worded question, so feel free to ask for clarification!

```cpp
int foo(std::string str, bool reverse = false) {
    if (!reverse) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            for (int j=i+1; j < str.length()+1; j++) {
                // ... return integer
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = str.length(); i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j=i-1; j > -1; j--) {
                // ... return integer
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To clarify, my use-case involves scanning for the first or last occurrence of any substring within a set of substrings. See the following:

```cpp
std::string foo(std::string str, std::unordered_set<std::string> substrings, bool reverse = false) {
    std::string current_substr;
    if (!reverse) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            for (int j=i+1; j < str.length()+1; j++) {
                current_substr = str.substr(i, j-i);
                if (substrings.contains(current_substr)) {
                    return current_substr;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = str.length(); i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j=i-1; j > -1; j--) {
                current_substr = str.substr(j, i-j);
                if (substrings.contains(current_substr)) {
                    return current_substr;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you scanning for? It isn't evident from the example. `find` and `rfind` may be what you are looking for.

Comment: "any substring within a set of substrings"? You're going to have to edit your post to a [mre] so we can see what the inner loop is doing if you want a generic one.

Comment: Consider a [mcve]. What you've shown and said does not explain the issue to me in order to understand why `find` and `rfind` are not what you are looking for.

Comment: I've updated the post with more clarification about my use-case. Please let me know if it is still insufficient.

Comment: TBH the code has much bigger problems, for instance the only sensible values of `j` are lengths that appear in `substrings`.  And the only sensible start positions `i` are the positions where a letter occurs that also starts at least one substring.

Comment: That's true—those are valid optimizations. I happen to know the maximum length of any substring in the set, so I only check substrings of the max length and lower (in my actual code). I kept that out of my code example, though, since I felt it wasn't essential to my question. And with regards to what you said before, Botje, std::reverse could be a solution to do away with the second set of for loops, though I'd be trading the somewhat duplicated code for the overhead of calling reverse. Thank you, nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

Any "merged" approach involves retyping the stepper function. Not exactly shorter or anymore readable. (Also untested so not even correct, I fear) Here is an approach using a lambda:

```
int i,j;
std::tie(i,j) = reverse ? std::make_tuple<int,int>(str.length(), str.length() - 1) : std::make_tuple(0, 1);
auto step = [&i,&j,reverse, len = str.length(), done = false]() mutable -> bool {
    if (done) return false;
    if (reverse) {
        j--;
        if (j < 0) {
            i--;
            j = i - 1;
            if (i <=  0) { done = true; }
        }
    } else {
        j++;
        if (j >= len) {
            i++;
            j = i + 1;
            if (i >= len) { done = true; }
        }
    }
    return !done;
};

while (step()) { /* construct a substring from i and j as before */
```

You could also wrap the core of `step` in an iterator but that is just throwing more code at it.

Answer (score 0):

Writing template function with iterator might simplify/factorize your code:

```
template <typename IT, typename F>
std::string foo(const std::unordered_set<std::string>& substrings,
                IT beg, IT end,
                F f)
{
    std::string current_substr;

    for (auto it1 = beg; it1 != end; ++it2) {
        for (auto it2 = beg + 1; it2 != end; ++it2) {
            current_substr = f(it1, it2);
            if (substrings.contains(current_substr)) {
                return current_substr;
            }
        }
    }
    return ""; // or throw?
}

std::string foo(const std::string& str,
                const std::unordered_set<std::string>& substrings,
                bool reverse = false)
{
    if (!reverse) {
        return foo(substring,
                   str.begin(), str.end(),
                   [](auto it1, auto it2){ return std::string(it1, it2); });
    } else {
        return foo(substring,
                   str.rbegin(), str.rend(),
                   [](auto rit1, auto rit2){ return std::string(rit2.base(), rit1.base()); });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I identified a way to merge the two loops by defining `start`, `end`, and `step` variables based on whether `reverse` was true, like so:

```cpp
std::string foo(std::string str, std::unordered_set<std::string> substrings, bool reverse = false) {
    std::string current_substr;
    int start = 0;
    int end = str.length();
    int step = 1;

    if (reverse) {
        start = str.length();
        end = 0;
        step = -1;
    }

    for (int i = start; i != end; i += step) {
        for (int j = i + step; j != end + step; j += step) {
            current_substr = str.substr(std::min(i,j), std::abs(j-i));
            if (substrings.contains(current_substr)) {
                return current_substr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although this *does* avoid the for-loop duplication I sought, the function still uses an if-statement to differentiate between values of `reverse`. This solution left me unsatisfied since it is slower than my original version, however trivial of a difference that may be.

After more thinking, I determined a way to initialize the `start`, `end`, and `step` variables *without* an if-statement. I did this by making use of the integer value of `reverse`, like so:

```cpp
std::string foo(std::string str, std::unordered_set<std::string> substrings, bool reverse = false) {
    std::string current_substr;
    int start = str.length() * reverse; // 0 if reverse is false, str.length() if reverse is true
    int end = str.length() * !reverse; // str.length() if reverse is false, 0 if reverse is true
    int step = !reverse - reverse; // 1 if reverse is false, -1 if reverse is true

    for (int i = start; i != end; i += step) {
        for (int j = i + step; j != end + step; j += step) {
            current_substr = str.substr(std::min(i,j), std::abs(j-i));
            if (substrings.contains(current_substr)) {
                return current_substr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you can even do away with the `start`, `end`, and `step` variables entirely and just use their values directly for concision's sake (at the expense of readability).

```cpp
std::string foo(std::string str, std::unordered_set<std::string> substrings, bool reverse = false) {
    std::string current_substr;
    for (int i = str.length() * reverse; i != str.length() * !reverse; i += !reverse - reverse) {
        for (int j = i + !reverse - reverse; j != str.length() * !reverse + !reverse - reverse; j += !reverse - reverse) {
            current_substr = str.substr(std::min(i,j), std::abs(j-i));
            if (substrings.contains(current_substr)) {
                return current_substr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```